# Maven can't find web.xml

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, war, web.xml

I'm getting the following error when building my maven-project with the command `mvn clean install`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war
(default-war) on project MyProject:
Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing 
WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)
```

I do have web.xml in the project. In the folder `web/WEB-INF/web.xml`

I am using IntelliJ IDEA. I can avoid this problem by adding the following to pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But I'd like to know why maven claims that web.xml is missing even though it's not and it is in the default location when creating a new web application project in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: The path web/WEB-INF/web.xml is not the default because there shouldn't be a web dir between WEB-INF/web.xml and the project root dir unless the project root dir is named 'web'.

Comment: Moved WEB-INF out of web-folder to project root and still getting the same error.

Comment: is your web.xml in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that you have `web.xml` in this path: `web/WEB-INF/web.xml`

With Maven, the `web.xml` should go in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` or you should change the `webXml` configuration of the war plugin (see here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#webXml)

Comment: In my case, I actually have web.xml in ./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF, but it doesn't run properly with `mvn jetty:run`, I'm not really sure why, it always says it that the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: Post your full pom file.  You have it in the right place unless you're overriding something